# batch - Removing a substring from a path while loop through a certain file type

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get only one directory name out of a known path while searching for certain file types. In the example below I am searching for mp4 video files then I want to convert them and move them into a subdirectory of the same name in a different parent directory. The path is known up until the file's direct parent directory, so I was trying to remove the known part of the path. This is giving me a lot of trouble though. In the example below, the variable `newDir` is empty after the set command and it shows only an input of `~13` with @echo on. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Example:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /R %%X in ("*.mp4") DO (
    set currDir="%%~pX"        &REM "\test1\test2\dir1"
    set newDir=%currDir:~13%   &REM dir1
    mkdir "C:\new\%newDir%"    &REM suppose to be "C:\new\dir1", mine is just "C:\new\"
    REM convert mp4 here
    cp %%X "C:\new\%newDir%"   &REM copies the file
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `enabledelayedexpansion` in `for` loop, you should use `!newDir!` instead of `%newDir%`, and also `!currDir:~13!` instead of `%currDir:~13%` to make delayed expansion happen.

[**update**] There're also small errors. You should be careful about the spaces and quotes when you `set` to variables. They are actual part of the string to be set. And you have `mkdir` the same directory several times, and also it's better to user `copy` or `xcopy` instead of 'cp' which should be from "Cygwin" or "MinGW32" or something. `xcopy` will automatically create folders for you if not exist.

To make your codes work, please see below. And just a suggestion that you'd better learn more basic knowledge about `bat` before starting programming.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /R %%X in ("*.mp4") DO (
    set currDir=%%~pX
    set newDir=!currDir:~13!
    REM mkdir "C:\new\!newDir!"
    REM convert mp4 here
    xcopy "%%X" "C:\new\!newDir!"
)
```

Comment: Things look a bit funky with the quotes (which I need because some directory names have spaces) and the exclamation points. Like it tries to make the directory `"C:\new\dir1\          "` but on initial testing it seems to work. I'll need additional testing to make sure that doesn't mess with other stuff.

Comment: Upon a second look it won't work. The conversion output which uses `"C:\new\!newDir!"` tries creating an output file `"C:\new\dir1\          \output.out"` or `"C:\new\dir1\          output.out"` (depending whether I add a slash or not), giving a "Cannot find path specified" in both cases.

Comment: The spaces in `"C:\new\dir1\          "` are actual from `"        &REM ..."` after each line. Please remove them, or put them in other lines.

Comment: Update the answer and have fixed errors in your script.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /R "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.mp4) DO (
 FOR %%m IN ("%%~dpa.") DO ECHO(XCOPY "%%a" "c:\new\%%~nm\"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required XCOPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(XCOPY` to `XCOPY` to actually copy the files.

I note that you're using a very `cygwin`nish `cp` in place of `copy`. Be careful of nameclashes. I changed the command to `xcopy` in order that the destination directory can be automatically generated if required. Note that you haven't said what you want to do if the destination file already exists.

Here's a trial run on my test directory:

```
XCOPY "U:\sourcedir\misc\90s\ACDC - Back in Black.mp4" "c:\new\90s\"
XCOPY "U:\sourcedir\misc\90s\extended\Kelly Rowland - Wor! (Freemasons Arabic Mix).mp4" "c:\new\extended\"
XCOPY "U:\sourcedir\misc\90s\extended\Kelly Rowland - Work (Freemasons Arabic Mix).mp4" "c:\new\extended\"
XCOPY "U:\sourcedir\one\dummyfile1.mp4" "c:\new\one\"
XCOPY "U:\sourcedir\t w o\dum myfile2.mp4" "c:\new\t w o\"
XCOPY "U:\sourcedir\t w o\dum ile2.mp4" "c:\new\t w o\"
```